# How to use a subquery and a literal within the same IN CLAUSE

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am trying to write a query that should with a WHERE clause that has an IN and the values inside should be a literal and a subquery. See example:

```
SELECT tbl1.Col1, tbl1.Col2, tbl1.Col3, tbl2.Col1, tbl2.Col2, tbl2.Col3
FROM tbl1 JOIN
     tbl2
     ON tbl1.col1 = tbl2.col1
where tbl2.col3 in 
((SELECT COL1 from tbl3 ),'literalvalue1', 'literalvalue2', 'literalvalue3'))
```

I googled and they suggested to put a top 1 to the subquery so that it turns to a scalar value but what if I need it to return all the values (multiple). I now get this error -

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, , >= or when the subquery is used as an
>   expression.

Is there a way to use a subquery and a literal within the same IN CLAUSE?
Appreciate your responses! Thanks.

Comment: Is a simple `or` out of the question?

Comment: compose your subquery so that the literal values you want also appear in its results

Answer (score 3):

You could use UNION ALL to add the values.

```
SELECT tbl1.Col1, tbl1.Col2, tbl1.Col3, tbl2.Col1, tbl2.Col2, tbl2.Col3
FROM tbl1 JOIN
     tbl2
     ON tbl1.col1 = tbl2.col1
where tbl2.col3 in 
                (SELECT COL1 
                 FROM tbl3 
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'literalvalue1'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT  'literalvalue2'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT  'literalvalue3');
```

You could also use a table-values constructor to avoid multiple UNION ALL.

```
SELECT tbl1.Col1, tbl1.Col2, tbl1.Col3, tbl2.Col1, tbl2.Col2, tbl2.Col3
FROM tbl1 JOIN
     tbl2
     ON tbl1.col1 = tbl2.col1
where tbl2.col3 in 
                (SELECT COL1 
                 FROM tbl3 
                UNION ALL
                SELECT val
                FROM (VALUES('literalvalue1'),('literalvalue2'),( 'literalvalue3'))x(val));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OR`:

```
where tbl2.col3 in (SELECT COL1 from tbl3 ) or
      tbl2.col3 in ('literalvalue1', 'literalvalue2', 'literalvalue3')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what I’ve used!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a join with union all form tbl3 and literalvalue1,2,3

```
  SELECT tbl1.Col1, tbl1.Col2, tbl1.Col3, tbl2.Col1, tbl2.Col2, tbl2.Col3
  FROM tbl1 
  JOIN tbl2   ON tbl1.col1 = tbl2.col1
  INNER JOIN  (

    SELECT COL1 from tbl3
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT 'literalvalue1'
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'literalvalue2'
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'literalvalue3'
  ) t  ON t.col1 =  tbl2.col3
```